# Mysql: Is there a more performant way of updating with nested aggregation?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am attempting to update a single value in table based on the result of calculated the sum of 2 nested queries. This is the query I have tried, it seems to work but is very slow.

```
update WALLET w
set total = 
 (
    select 
        min(
            (select sum(earned) from WALLET_TRANSACTION t where t.wallet_id = w.id and type not in ('FEE', 'REDEEM')) + 
            (select sum(earned) from WALLET_TRANSACTION t where t.wallet_id = w.id and type in ('FEE', 'REDEEM'))
        ) as sumredeemed
    from WALLET_TRANSACTION
 );
```

It currently takes 52.77 seconds to update a single WALLET entry.

Is there anyway I can optimise this query to speed it up in Mysql 8?

WALLET table:

```
mysql> show create table WALLET\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: WALLET
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `WALLET` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reference` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `target` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `target_manually_adjusted` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `deleted` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_modified_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `reference` (`reference`,`user_id`),
  KEY `wallet_reference` (`reference`),
  KEY `wallet_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `wallet_target_manually_adjusted` (`target_manually_adjusted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1611167816726 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

WALLET_TRANSACTION:

```
    Table: WALLET_TRANSACTION
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `WALLET_TRANSACTION` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `wallet_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `merchant_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `merchant_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `merchant_logo_url` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `product_redeem_window_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `offer_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `outlet_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `offer_type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_delta_type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_reference` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_external_reference` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `earned` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `spent` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `earned_percent` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `partner` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `commission` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `date_of_transaction` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `approved` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `enabled` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  `deleted` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_modified_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`,`wallet_id`),
  KEY `wallet_transaction_type` (`type`),
  KEY `wallet_transaction_status` (`status`),
  KEY `wallet_transaction_wallet_id` (`wallet_id`),
  KEY `wallet_transaction_approved` (`approved`),
  KEY `wallet_transaction_spent` (`spent`),
  KEY `wallet_transaction_earned` (`earned`),
  KEY `wallet_transaction_prwid` (`product_redeem_window_id`),
  KEY `wallet_transaction_client_external_reference` (`client_external_reference`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1611097810451 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: When posting query-optimization questions, you should include the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each table, so we can see data types and indexes currently defined in your tables. Also it would help to see the EXPLAIN analysis for this query.

Comment: "a single value" -- Meaning that there is only one row to update?

Comment: No multiple row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you seem to just want the sum of `earned` for matching rows:

```
update WALLET w
    set total = (select sum(t.earned)
                 from WALLET_TRANSACTION t
                 where t.wallet_id = w.id
                );
```

I see no reason to split this into fee versus no free and then add the results back together.

Answer (score 1):

One could do it this way without subqueries:

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE WALLET SET total = 0;

UPDATE WALLET AS w JOIN WALLET_TRANSACTION AS t ON t.wallet_id = w.id
SET w.total = w.total + t.earned

COMMIT;
```

Make sure there's an index on `t.wallet_id`.

I assume `w.id` is a primary key, so it's indexed already.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the final `from WALLET_TRANSACTION` -- You don't need to redo the calculation for every row of the table.

In general, it is quite fine to do

```
SELECT expression;
```

-- that is, without a FROM.  In some situations, you might need the pseudo table `dual`:

```
SELECT expression FROM DUAL;
```

Another thing... `MIN(col)` is for aggregation across *rows*, while `LEAST(expression, expression, ...)` is the "min" of those expressions.  So, also change `MIN` to `LEAST`.